# get_pages sort alphabetically by meta value

Tags: custom-field, sort, meta-value

I operate a real estate website, and I have a list of homes we are selling. I am using a bunch of custom fields to store information about the homes. When you click on a home in the home listing page (page, not post), it takes you to a dedicated page (again, not post) for that home. I'm very new to PHP and Wordpress.

Right now the code I am using (get_pages) is working to display all the pages I want it to, but it is sorting by the post_date. Instead, what I want it to do is sort alphabetically by one of my Custom Field meta values; specifically, to sort A-Z by the street address. Is there any way I can use the "sort_column" parameter to do this? Everything I've found from searching has been related to getting *posts* instead of *pages*.

Here is my current code that gets the pages:

```
<?php $listingPages = get_pages( 
        array(
            'sort_order' => 'ASC',
            'sort_column' => 'post_date',
            'meta_key' => 'houseNo',
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        )
    );

    foreach( $listingPages as $page ) {     
        $content = $page->post_content;
        if ( ! $content ) // Check for empty page
            continue;

        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    ?>
        <div class="listingPreview">
            <h2 class="listingTitle"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link( $page->ID ); ?>"><span class="houseNo"><?php echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'houseNo', true); ?></span>&nbsp;<?php echo get_post_meta($page->ID, 'streetAdd', true); ?></a></h2>
        </div>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Please excuse my dirty code, I'm a complete noob and am totally on my own with this and have no professional training.

So basically I'm wondering if I could do something like this with the sort_column parameter (this obviously doesn't work):

```
<?php $listingPages = get_pages( 
        array(
            'sort_order' => 'ASC',
            'sort_column' => get_post_meta('streetAdd'),
            'meta_key' => 'houseNo',
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        )
    );
```

I don't even know if I'm asking the right question, or if I need to use some sort of custom query called from functions.php or something. I'm open to whatever I need to do to achieve this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers! Have you tried looking at the Codex page for get_post_meta or WP_Query? You can probably answer your own question by looking there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The get_pages function is rather old and really shouldn't be used anymore. Use a get_posts instead (a Page is just a special type of Post):

```
$listingPages = get_posts( 
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'streetAdd',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    )
);
```

Comment: Okay that worked; one caveat though. It took me a minute to figure out that the default post count is 5, so I had to add in the parameter `'numberposts' => 100,`. Is there any way to make the numberposts infinite?

Comment: Use `posts_per_page` instead of `numberposts`, and set it to -1.

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm. Thanks for your help!